# Using MERGE with Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, merge

I am trying to insert a record into my table if it doesn't already exist.
If it does exist, I want it to update.

I saw this example someone else posted:

```
MERGE INTO mytable d
USING (SELECT 1 id, 'x' name from dual) s
ON (d.id = s.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET d.name = s.name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id, name) VALUES (s.id, s.name);
```

My current stored procedure looks like this:

```
procedure savePublicId(P_ACCNO in varchar2, P_PUBLICID in varchar2) is
begin
     update cc_custprofiles cpr
        set cpr.publicid       =  P_PUBLICID
      where cpr.customerlong_cpr  =  'C'||P_ACCNO
        and key_cpr = 'SINGLE';

     commit;
end;
```

There are no identity columns in this table (I know...) so I can't do a catch.
I have tried to change that `merge` to match my table structure, but I am new to Oracle so not really sure what I am doing :D

I have come up with this:

```
merge into cc_custprofiles cpr
using (select 1 customerlong_cpr, 'x' publicid, 'SINGLE' key_cpr from dual) dual
on (cpr.customerlong_cpr = dual.customerlong_cpr)
when matched then update set cpr.publicid = P_PUBLICID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (customerlong_cpr, publicid, key_cpr) values (P_ACCNO, P_PUBLICID, 'SINGLE');
```

But I don't think that is right. Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there with your merge statement. I think you're after something more like this:

```
MERGE INTO cc_custprofiles tgt
USING (SELECT 'C' || p_accno customerlong_cpr,
          p_publicid publicid,
          'SINGLE' key_cpr
     FROM   dual) src
ON (tgt.customerlong_cpr = src.customerlong_cpr AND tgt.key_cpr = src.key_cpr)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.publicid = src.publicid
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (tgt.customerlong_cpr, tgt.publicid, tgt.key_cpr)
  VALUES (src.customerlong_cpr, src.publicid, src.key_cpr);
```

The point of a merge statement is to take results from a source table or subquery, and decide whether to insert them or update them in the target table. In your case, since you're using parameters to decide what to insert, you need to put them into a `select ... from dual` subquery, so you can use it as the source subquery in the merge statement.

Your join conditions (aka the `ON` clause) are the predicates you use to identify the rows - in your case, that appears to be:

```
where cpr.customerlong_cpr  =  'C'||P_ACCNO
        and key_cpr = 'SINGLE';
```

from your update statement.

Then it's just a matter of updating or inserting the relevant values as required.

N.B. I always use `tgt` and `src` as the aliases for the target table and source table/subquery respectively; I find this helps me to keep things straight in my head whilst I'm writing the query. You may or may not find this convention helpful.